# ERRORES cannot resolve symbol REQUEST_LOCATION

Tags: java, android

me estan saliendo los siguientes errorres: 
Error 1: cannot resolve symbol REQUEST_LOCATION, 
Error 2: FusedLocationApi, aparece tachado.

cuando trato de solicitar permisos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el framento del codigo

```
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000); // milliseconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // the fastest rate in milliseconds at which your app can handle location updates
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


// this line of error



        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            // permission has been granted, continue as usual
            Location myLocation =
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

te voy a explicar lo que te esta pasando:

1) `ActivityCompat.requestPermission` recibe 3 parametros el primero es la actividad que lo estas enviando bien, el segundo es un Array con los permisos que deseas obtener ese también lo estas haciendo bien, el tercer parametro es el requestCode que no es mas que un numero que envias y con el que puedes preguntar por la respuesta en el metodo `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

Para que se elimine el error solo debes crear una variable global asi:

```
public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1; //Pueses colocar cualquier numero
```

2) Con respecto a que te salga tachado `FusedLocationApi` eso significa que ese método esta deprecado osea que esta desaconsejado para su uso.

Aqui te dejo un link donde hablan hacerca de ese tema : [FusedLocationApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481789/android-locationservices-fusedlocationapi-deprecated)

Comment: Correcto, pero sabes, hice lo que me aconsejaste, y ahora me muestra error en "THIS": ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this; dice que required:'android.app.activity'

Comment: Que error te dice ya?